# Do...While loop with probably if ... else statment inside with temporarily variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, do-while

I am asked, after giving me
an initial_population(7),
a growth_rate(1.2%),
an initial_year (2011), and a formula that link the final population to the inital one with the following :

```
initial_population * exp ( (final_year - initial_year) * (rate/ 100.0))
```

For a certain population entered, I have made this population grow year after year with this following forumla :

```
    double pc(0.0); // pc = population entered
    while (pc <= initial_population)
        {
        cout << "How many billion (> 7) ? ";
        cin >> pc;
        };

    int temp(year);
    do {
        ++temp;
        cout << "Population in " << temp << " : " << 
        initial_population * exp ( (final_year - initial_year) * (rate/ 100.0))
        << endl;
        } 
        while ( pc > initial_population * 
                     exp ( (final_year - initial_year) * (rate/ 100.0)));
```

I would like now to make this population growth_rate being divided by two anytime the initial population doubles and to make it show until the population has reached the entered population "pc". Obviously, the process must take longer than when the growth_rate wasn't divided and the outcome should look like :

```
Population in 2012 : 7.085 ; growth rate : 1.2 %
Population in 2013 : 7.17 ; growth rate : 1.2 %
Population in 2014 : 7.257 ; growth rate : 1.2 %
Population in 2015 : 7.344 ; growth rate : 1.2 %
...
Population in 2068 : 13.87 ; growth rate : 1.2 %
Population in 2069 : 14.04 ; growth rate : 0.6 %
Population in 2070 : 14.12 ; growth rate : 0.6 %
...
Population en 2195 : 29.02 ; growth rate : 0.3 %
```

All I know in C++ yet is until the for and do while loops, with of course the if else statements.

Is there anyonone who can help me with that, I don't need to have the perfect answer, just some help on how to start with this part. for example how to make the statement when the population doubles, etc.. ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Save the initial_population value, multiplied by 2, in a separate variable. Then check on each iteration if the current_population (a variable I made up, but it's value should be obvious) is greater than or equal to the other stored variable, multiply the value by 2 again and split the growth rate in half. Something like this:

```
double population_doubled_check_val = initial_population * 2;
double current_population;
do {
    ++temp;
    current_population = initial_population * exp ( (final_year - initial_year) * (rate/ 100.0));
    cout << "Population in " << temp << " : " << current_population << endl;
    if (current_population >= population_doubled_check_val) {
        population_doubled_check_val *= 2;
        rate /= 2;
        }
    } 
while ( current_population < pc );
```

I don't think copypasta of that will work, but it should give you an idea. On an aside, it's helpful if you provide a full, minimum implementation necessary to exemplify the problem but still compiles. For no other reason than to get answers faster. :)